# How to distinguish between ntlm & ntlmv2 authentication

Tags: ntlm, ntlmv2

I'm viewing some legacy code and attempting to determine if the application is using ntlm or ntlmv2.

Viewing the source the response header set to "WWW-Authenticate", "NTLM".

But I'm not sure if this is an indication of the authentication type.

How to distinguish between ntlm & ntlmv2 authentication ?

Comment: Have a look at this link.
[https://richardkok.wordpress.com/2011/02/03/wireshark-determining-a-smb-and-ntlm-version-in-a-windows-environment/]

Comment: @zakaiter link is broken?

Comment: https://richardkok.wordpress.com/2011/02/03/wireshark-determining-a-smb-and-ntlm-version-in-a-windows-environment/

Comment: **Same kind of question is asked here, hope it helps** [How to determine NTLMv1 VS NTLMv2 traffic in netmon](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/dcf004ca-ae72-4d04-ab07-10ece3143ae6/how-to-determine-ntlmv1-vs-ntlmv2-traffic-in-netmon?forum=netmon)

Answer (score -1):

You can't unless you dissect the messages.

Comment: thanks, is there a signature within the messages that will determine this ?

Comment: Read the specs for the type 1 message: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc236641.aspx